# iOS 8 Parse.com update and pf geopoint current location

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8

So I recently updated to the latest Parse SDK that's compatible with iOS 8 and I add the two keys NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription...but for some reason [PFGeoPoint geopointForCurrentLocationInBackground] is not being called....and I don't understand why.

[image]

and here is a snippet of the code:

```
                     [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
                         if(!error){
                             NSLog(@"Got current geopoint!");

....


else{
                                     UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:[error description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
                                     [errorAlert show];                                 }
                             }];
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[PFGeoPoint geopointForCurrentLocationInBackground]` will only be called if you have first called your `CLLocationManager` engaged and have asked the user for permission to show their location.

You also need to update the `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status` method for iOS 8.

Something like this is what I use:

```
// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
else {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //<<PUT YOUR CODE HERE AFTER LOCATION IS UPDATING>>
}
```

You also need to implement the locationmanager delegate method to handle changes is location authorization status, like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied");
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Not Enabled" message:@"The app can’t access your current location.\n\nTo enable, please turn on location access in the Settings app under Location Services." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
    {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
        if (currentLocation) {
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate setCurrentLocation:currentLocation];
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
    {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
        if (currentLocation) {
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate setCurrentLocation:currentLocation];
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
        break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I just do this in one view controller or every view controller I use location in? If the app asks for location in one view controller and the user says yes, they've given the app permission to use location whenever right? (Either foreground or foreground and background)

Comment: Correct, once the app has permission that permission stays until the user changes the permissions in the Settings app. To prevent problems with edge cases, I implement these methods in every ViewController that might use location services (via a class extension) and I recommend something similar if you are using location services a lot.