# Parse with swift testing geopoints on real device

Tags: swift, parse-platform, geolocation

When I go to test my application on my actual iphone in xcode, do I have to simulate a location or can I use my home location. If I simulate it in one of the given areas it works fine, but I do not know how to test for my location I am developing at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste use this PFGeoPoint function:

```
geopointForCurrentLocationInBackground
```

You need to have the location permission in your app though, see this:
[iOS 8 Parse.com update and pf geopoint current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111631/ios-8-parse-com-update-and-pf-geopoint-current-location?answertab=active#tab-top)